# Paragon Paths for Lazy Warlords

Tags: dnd-4e, character-advancement, paragon-path, warlord

> A Lazy character is one using powers that don't allow any attack or damage roll by the attacker. The most basic example of such power is [Commander's Strike](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=1061).

I have a player in my table that is building a lazy warlord, and he is kinda frustrated that when he reach level 11, any paragon path he can pick will have a 11th level encounter power with either an attack or damage roll. So, my question is: **Is there any Paragon Path with a 11th and/or 20th level "lazy" powers?**

Multiclass options are allowed. He didn't choose any multiclass feat yet.

Comment: Just too make it clear, we are aware that some PPs are very good for a lazy warlord (like Battle Captain), and he can easily ignore the extra attack powers and stay with the lazy power. We are just curious if he can stay attack-less for the entire campaign.

Comment: If they are making a LazyLord I would recommend not using a straight Warlord, since at lower levels especially they don't have quite enough good powers. I would suggest using a hybrid, since they don't really lose all that much and gain a lot (Artificer and Bard are especially good). That would also allow them to take a PP with an E11 they can actually use.

Comment: @diego That depends on the party. I'm running a campaign where one of the players is using mostly these kind of powers. His party members are mostly Essentials characters with powers that trigger off their melee basic, so his turn can be pretty damaging. Recently, at level 8, he let the party's slayer attack 3 extra times in a round, which was kind of a big deal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of a pure Warlord PP that has a 'lazy' E11 (If you hybrid there are some decent options however). There is however the feat [Reserve Maneuver](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=512) that allows you to replace any encounter power you have with an encounter power from your class that you don't already have. So you can replace the Battle Captain's E11 with a Warlord E1, E3 or E7 power.